# Web scraping multiple twitter sites

Tags: r, loops, web-scraping, twitter

The goal is to scrape multiple tweets of twitter, their likes etc. I somehow cannot find a way to do that with multiple different tweets, for one tweet it works perfectly.

I have already set up the scraping for individual tweets in R. Code is pasted below. But, I cannot implement that for multiple sites.

```
    site <- "https://twitter.com/btspavedyou/status/1146055736130019334"
    page <- read_html(site)

    handles <- page %>%
      html_nodes(".js-action-profile") %>%
      html_text() %>%
      sub(".*@", "", .) %>% 
      print()
    text_new <- page %>%
      html_nodes("p.TweetTextSize") %>%
      html_text() %>%
      print()     
    time <- page %>%
      html_nodes("._timestamp") %>%
      html_text() %>%
      print()

    all_data_tweet <- data.frame(
      page=site, 
      author=handles, 
      text=text_new, 
      time=time
      )
    all_data_tweet
```

Now when trying the the same with the following ten pages it does not work (tried for looks and apply in association with functions.

```
  multiple_pages <- c("https://twitter.com/Swiftandoned/status/1146494919344717824", "https://twitter.com/Swiftandoned/status/1146149790016688128","https://twitter.com/baylee_corbello/status/1146494887875022854","https://twitter.com/angiegon00/status/1146494850486820864", "https://twitter.com/gallica_/status/1146494826289999872", "https://twitter.com/RomuHDV/status/1146494814604673029","https://twitter.com/mathebula_boity/status/1146494779666178049","https://twitter.com/mathebula_boity/status/1146487751774285825","https://twitter.com/mathebula_boity/status/1146494417697681408","https://twitter.com/mathebula_boity/status/1146494307324575744")
```

The result should be that this what I have for one tweet is produced for multiple tweets:

```
                                                        page         author                                                 text    time
1 https://twitter.com/btspavedyou/status/1146055736130019334 KPOP_predict18           Sehun and Jisoo together in a drama, 2020. 2. Juli
2 https://twitter.com/btspavedyou/status/1146055736130019334         na1_27 Well i guess there is nothing about iKON AND HANBIN  2. Juli
3 https://twitter.com/btspavedyou/status/1146055736130019334    btspavedyou                               I'm sure he is 'okay'  2. Juli
4 https://twitter.com/btspavedyou/status/1146055736130019334         na1_27                          I really hope so, thank you 2. Juli
```

Comment: Did you notice that there are R packages for that purpose ? `twitteR`for instance. It should be easier than web scraping

Comment: Yes, they cannot get the responses to tweets so I need to scrape them individually. Thank you, however!

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways to solve, but doing minor modifications I'd use `bind_rows` from `dplyr`:

```
readTweet <-function(url){
  page <- read_html(url)

  handles <- page %>%
    html_nodes(".js-action-profile") %>%
    html_text() %>%
    sub(".*@", "", .)
  text_new <- page %>%
    html_nodes("p.TweetTextSize") %>%
    html_text()     
  time <- page %>%
    html_nodes("._timestamp") %>%
    html_text() 

  all_data_tweet <- data.frame(
    page = url, 
    author = handles, 
    text = text_new, 
    time = time
    )

  return(all_data_tweet)
}

df <- bind_rows(
  lapply(list_of_urls, readTweet)
  )
```

You don't need to create an .id since you have the page url as column.

Comment: Dear Jose, quick question, the "site" variable, how is it produced? Shouldn't it be "list_of_urls"?

Comment: Jose, I realized, I think the "list_of_urls" was misleading. It is just a vector of a data.frame that contains the URLs that I would like to get. Any way?

Comment: site was in fact meant to be url inside the function. And list_of_urls is exactly just a character vector with the urls that you want to scrape, or multiple_pages as in your question.